Which duplo digit is 6 or 9?
Not every question has to be as hard as possible, here is an easy one.

I joined my kids playing with duplo, and found out that the duplo 9 and 6 look exactly the same if you turn one of them 180 degrees. So I decided to build the structure below. Of course I didn't use any glue or tape. Could you reason which of the following digits is the 9 and which is the 6?



 If the green is 9 it would lead to this scenario:


 


 As you can see the yellow and green bricks on the bottom left are unsupported and would fall away down…

Ergo

 The green is 6 and the purple is 9.


Very helpful to draw the studs :)

Alternative reasoning: rot13(oybpxf ner pbyberq va ebltovi beqre)

This matches what is currently being sold by LEGO.

@EngineerToast, that is exactly the set we have :)

One of the things that was not obvious to me was that the construction was being held up, and therefore, pieces could fall down. Instead, I imagined it lying flat on a table, which makes either configuration possible. @Lezzup 's picture forces the intended perception.

@Jlee I am in two minds as to whether the op is looking at it from the top or from the side… if it is from the top the whole left side would collapse! From the side I think only the bottom part would fall depending on how you hold it. Either way my refutation still works! It seems more likely that it’s from the side because the back ground looks more like a wall.

assumption used: the pieces have stubs on the bottom

@PDT, it is indeed from the side, we have painted the wall blue ;)

Because the correct answer is already given, here is the other photo I took, that explains everything without words:

 



 Green is 6, purple is 9.

Because:

 if it was the other way round (green 9 and purple 6), then nothing would hold the left (white-yellow-green-yellow) and right (red-red-yellow-blue) sides of the structure together, and the left side would fall away since you're only holding the right side.


Insight: the numbers are colour-coded onto a rainbow.
Green is in the centre of the rainbow, violet is at the end.
6 is near the centre of the digits, 9 is at the end.
Therefore the 6 is green, the 9 is violet.


This is more like cheeting in my opinion. I had thought about it to explicit put the instruction there, to not look it up... but yeah, this answer is technically correct, and we have actually this specific duplo set :)

This wasn't from looking it up, but I did validate my answer before posting :)
